# Assign Value from Closure to Variable Swift

Tags: ios, swift, closures, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm trying to assign the value I get back from a closure to a variable I have assigned outside the scope of the closure.

I want to do this so i'm able to use this var outside my closure in order to be neat and not have all this nested code inside this closure.

I am using Alamofire for the requests and swify-json to help parse the json.

I'm getting the following:

```
Error: variable 'userId' captured by a closure before being initialized
```

Here is my code calling my closure function:

```
var userId: Int

get()
{
    data in
    userId = data["used_id"].intValue
}
```

Here is my implementation of my get() function:

```
func get(param: [String: AnyObject] = [String: AnyObject](), completion: (JSON) -> ())
{
    Alamofire.request(.GET, "apiendpoint.com", parameters: param)
    .responseJSON
    {
        response in
            switch response.result
            {
                case .Success:
                    let jsonData = JSON(data: response.data!)
                    completion(jsonData)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any and all help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `var userId: Int` to `var userId: Int!`

The reason is that the closure is expecting a value to be in the variable when you "capture it". By using a forcefully unwrapped variable, the closure will be able to capture it as it holds a value of nil, which you can then assign a value to when the closure is called.

Comment: Well i've gotten further! It will build now but if I try to use my var (userId) outside the closure it crashes because it is still nil. But inside the closure userId is not nil, it is an actual value.

Comment: i assume you are trying to do access the variable like so:
var userId: Int!
get() { userId = ... }
print(userId)
If so, at the point print(userId) is called the network request has not actually been completed due to the fact that a network request is asynchronous. print is being called instantly after you call get() obviously not allowing enough time for the request to complete. The solution to this is to perform what actions you want to do with the userId variable inside the closure itself. Also if the answer i provide resolved your question please tick it as the correct answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for you help. This helps but I would still like to access that variable outside my closure but i'm afraid your right. The asynchronous request isn't completed before the print is executed. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you can still access your variable outside the closure as long as you know where you are trying to access it will only be called after network request is complete. in the closure (aka "completion handler") you can call another function that will continue on with what you wanna do.